# All mails are not fetched when i was using EIMAP with YIi

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to fetch  mails from my Thunderbird mail account.
It only fetches only 50,60 mails. My account contain total of 175 mails. I used the flag `SEARCH_All` of `EImap`. But it doesn't fetch all mails. Can anyone help me,what is my error?

```
Yii::import('ext.
EIMap.EIMap', true);
    $imap = new EIMap('{myserver.com:993}/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'yourusername', 'yourpassword');
    if ($imap->connect()) {
      $unseen = $imap->searchmails(EIMap::SEARCH_ALL);
      foreach ($unseen as $key => $values) {
        $mail = $imap->getMail($values);
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here 
$imap = new EIMap('{myserver.com:993}/imap/ssl}**INBOX**', 'yourusername', 'yourpassword');

You are checking only in folder INBOX. Where can be 50-60 emails. Rest of them can be in other folders.

---

You code below, because EIMap by default add 4 parameter as UTF8 into imap_search($this->stream, $criteria, SE_UID, $this->serverEncoding) and this can eliminate some emails, but I'm not sure.

**$mailboxCheck = $imap->getCheck();**

**$result = $imap->getMailboxOverview("1:{$mailboxCheck->Nmsgs}");**

Comment: I am trying to fetch mails of inbox folder only,,thats why i given it as inbox.